# I can't achieve modelformset set initial values to the extra forms

Tags: django, django-forms

This is my code:

```
GaugeFormSet = modelformset_factory(GaugeConfiguration,form=GaugeConfigurationForm, extra=3, fields='__all__') 
gauges = GaugeConfiguration.objects.filter(configuration=configuration)
gaugeformset = GaugeFormSet(queryset=gauges, initial=[{'configuration':configuration,}])
```

The problem is that the initial parameter only applies only to the first extra form, and not the others.

I found this in [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#id2):

> **Providing initial values**
>
> As with regular formsets, it’s possible to specify initial data for forms in the formset by specifying an initial parameter when instantiating the model formset class returned by modelformset_factory(). However, with model formsets, the initial values only apply to extra forms, those that aren’t attached to an existing model instance. If the extra forms with initial data aren’t changed by the user, they won’t be validated or saved.

In theory, initial values should apply to all the extra forms. Why is applying only to the first extra form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For formsets, `initial` is a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary is the initial data for **one** form.

This allows you to have different initial data for each extra form, for example:

```
initial = [{'configuration': 'configuration1',},
          {'configuration': 'configuration2',},
          {'configuration': 'configuration3',},
          ]
```

If you want the same initial data for every form, you can do:

```
initial = [{'configuration': configuration,}] * 3)
```